# ограничение строки в js

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть скрипт который должен ограничивать строку по кол-во символов и в конце троеточие добавлять, но добавляет только троеточие

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="news-content">
  <br><br><br><br><br>
  dfgdfgdhfhfghfghfgdfhgfhdfgdfgdfgsdfdfgdfghfghfgfghfghfghfgh
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var size = 5,
        newsContent= $('.news-content'),
        newsText = newsContent.text();
        
    if(newsText.length > size) {
      newsContent.text(newsText.slice(0, size) + ' ...');
    }
  });
</script>
```

самое забавное, что здесь https://codepen.io/suhodolskiy/pen/qEJQRQ работает, а у меня нет

P.S. библиотека подключается одна и та же

Comment: А в консоли браузера что пишется? (когда ‎‎"не работает")

Comment: @yar85, ничего не пишется

Comment: Проблема не воспроизводится. Нужно добавить в вопрос либо код/условия для ее воспроизведения, либо сообщение об ошибке. Без этого, ответить на вопрос просто невозможно.

Comment: @yar85, нет никаких ошибок, текст в блоке div был сильно спущен и много пробелов вначале

Comment: Без полной информации о проблеме (**либо** условий ее воспроизведения, **либо** сообщения об ошибке), вопрос бесполезен - это понятно, или требует объяснения?

Comment: Этот вопрос я уже отредактировал, но в своих будущих вопросах - пожалуйста, добавляй информацию сам.

Comment: @yar85, не было никаких ошибок

Answer (score 5):

Решением будет использование метода [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) - он возвращает копию входной строки (от которой вызван), но без пробельных символов в начале и конце:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="news-content">
  <br><br><br><br><br> <!-- лишние пробелы перед текстом -->
  dfgdfgdhfhfghfghfgdfhgfhdfgdfgdfgsdfdfgdfghfghfgfghfghfghfgh
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var size = 5,
        newsContent = $('.news-content'),
        newsText = newsContent.text().trim(); // ◀
    if(newsText.length > size) {
      newsContent.text(newsText.slice(0, size) + ' ...');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

нашел причину, текст в блоке div был сильно спущен и много пробелов вначале